# How to automate the provisioning of SharePoint Webparts on a SharePoint Online modern pages?

Tags: workflow, azure-logic-apps, sharepoint-online

I want to create a SharePoint Online site automatically with some custom apps, which I deployed in my appstore before.
They are generally available.
How can I publish those webparts automatically on a site with a workflow? Can I use PowerAutomate or LogicApps and how I can automatise it there?

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: As per my knowledge, no such action can be used to provision SPFx web parts automatically on a site using Power Automate. Not sure about LogicApps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using power automation and logic app. The workaround would be creating the SharePoint webparts programmatically and call HTTP POST URL of the [logic Request connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres?tabs=consumption) from your SharePoint webparts programmatically along with the details you need to pass to your workflow.